# message: "Network Error", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_NETWORK"

Tags: reactjs, axios, vite

Windows 11 running Ubuntu 22.04 under Windows Subsystem for Linux.
Postgresql has been installed on Ubuntu and is up and working.

I am attempting to read a table from my database using axios in a react component.

VITE is being used.

My backend server.js code is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// PostgreSQL database configuration
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'admin',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'SRDB',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
});

// Route handler for fetching products
app.get('/api/products', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Query products from the database
      const { rows } = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM products');
      console.log('Products:', rows);
        // Send products data as JSON response
      res.json(rows);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
  });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
  console.log('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

axios is called within this code:

```
import HeaderBar from "./HeaderBar.jsx";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./Footer.jsx";
import { CartProvider } from "./Context.jsx";
import { UserProvider } from "./Context.jsx";
import { ProductProvider } from "./Context.jsx";
import axios from "axios";
import Time from "./Time.jsx";

const AppLayout = () => {
  const [UserData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const [ProductData, setProductData] = useState(["not ready yet"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Example: Fetch user data and product data
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      // Replace the following with your actual API call or data loading logic
      // const userData = await fetch("/api/user");
      const userData = {
        name: "John Doe",
        email: "",
      };
      setUserData(userData);
    };

    const fetchProductData = async () => {
      console.log(Time(), "Fetching product data...");
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/products");
        setProductData(response);
        console.log(response);
      } catch (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log("Error fetching product data:", error);
      }
    };

    // Fetch data when the component mounts
    fetchUserData();
    fetchProductData();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once when the component mounts

  return (
    <>
      <UserProvider value={{ UserData }}>
        <ProductProvider value={{ ProductData }}>
          <CartProvider>
            <HeaderBar />
            <Outlet />
            <Footer className="footer" />
          </CartProvider>
        </ProductProvider>
      </UserProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default AppLayout;
```

When invoking from the application, I've found the following errors in the console:

```
{stack: "AxiosError@http://lo…", message: "Network Error", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_NETWORK", config: Object, …}


config: {transitional: Object, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
```

I have search the internet in general and also Stack overflow.

I have tried all combinations of "http:" and "https:" with both "localhost:" and "127.0.0.1:" prepending "3000/api/products" None of these combinations work.

I have verified:

```
      const { rows } = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM products');
      console.log('Products:', rows);
```

is correctly returning the data to the server from the table by reviewing the console.log

Comment: You're going to need the `cors()` middleware in your Express app to support that cross-origin request

Comment: Axios' default error encapsulation is generally terrible. You can typically get better information from the dev-tools _Network_ and _Console_ panels but I do find this is usually clearer... `console.error("Error fetching product data:", error.response?.data, error.toJSON())`

Comment: console.error("Error fetching product data:", error.response?.data, error.toJSON()) did not give me any additional information than what has previously been shown.

Comment: Ok, so how about your _Network_ panel? Does the response have a status? If so, what is it? Is there a response body with any details? Are there any errors at all in the _Console_ panel?

Comment: I do believe the issue is CORS as I had not previously used it in the application.  I am struggling to get the defineConfig correct and have a functioning server.  Right now, I'm heading out of town for a week and will have to set this aside until my return.  A pointer to great documentation or examples of this would greatly help.